# using angularjs to refresh view's data automatically when the data in database is changed

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to use angularJs to refresh view's data automatically when the data in database is changed? Please help me how to do it
I made this script, but as you can see the data only refresh if viewData() is triggered.

```
$scope.viewData = function(){
    $http.get("sample.php").then(function(response){
        $scope.mine = response.data;
    });
}
```

I want to create page like timeline in twitter which can load new tweets without refreshing the page. Thank you

Comment: Angular alone I don't believe you can do this. you might have to use a web socket and close it on $destroy

Comment: you can do it also with longpolling with php

Answer (score 0):

You can do longpolling like this from Angular side:

```
setInterval($scope.vievData, 1000);
```

since `setInterval` is not monitored by Angular you will have to add the following line in `$scope.viewData`

```
$scope.$$phase || $scope.$digest();
```

immediately after `$scope.mine=...`

This will refresh `$scope.mine` every second regardless of the changes in DB, it is a bit crude.  To do this only when the values are changed in the database you will probably have to use WebSockets, but that is a bit more complex, both front and back.